# Read non-static property value of a subclass via Reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

I am implementing a variation of the `Command` design pattern. I have an abstract `CodedCommand` class with some subclasses, each of one with an overriden "Code" property of type `char`. Each subclass has then the responsibility to "encapsulate" its own `Code` letter to which it is associated.

The use case is: when some serial parser receive a char/byte, I want to create an instance of the appropriate subclass, to further process the command payload.

My problem is: I don't know how to get the specific value from each subclass.

My current implementation is below. The problem, highlighted with a comment, is that `type.GetProperty("Code")` is returning null!

```
internal abstract class CodedCommand
{
    internal abstract char Code { get; }
}

internal class EventA : CodedCommand
{
    internal override char Code => 'A';
}

internal class EventB : CodedCommand
{
    internal override char Code => 'B';
}

public class CommandCreator
{
    Dictionary<char, Type> _typeMap 
        = new Dictionary<char, Type>();

    public CommandCreator()
    {
        var types = GetType().Assembly.GetTypes()
                                     .Where(type => type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(CodedCommand)))
                                     .Where(type => !type.IsAbstract);

        foreach (var type in types)
        {
            var field = type.GetProperty("Code");  // returns null!!!
            var value = field.GetValue(null);
            var code = (char)value;

            _typeMap[code] = type;
        }
    }


    CodedCommand BuildCommand(char code)
    {
        _typeMap.TryGetValue(code, out Type type);

        if (type != null)
        {
            return (CodedCommand)(Activator.CreateInstance(type));
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

So my question is how can I fix this design?

Comment: Just change to `type.GetProperty("Code", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);`. Not that it will help to resolve your problem (because the next line will fail anyway), but at least you will get property you wanted to.

Comment: @Evk you are right, next line now has a problem. How could I solve that next problem, then? "Non-static method requires a target".

Comment: Because this property is not static - you need to create an instance to get the value. For example: `var value = field.GetValue(Activator.CreateInstance(type));` (that's the same as `var value = new EventB().Code`). Drawback is it requires for all commands to have parameterless constructor (cannot enforce that at compile time), plus creates one instance (not a problem if there is not much code expected in constructor of a command).

Comment: My constructive but possibly unhelpful suggestion: back up and do this without reflection and runtime type checking. People can tell you how to do what you're trying to do, but you almost certainly shouldn't be doing it. The developer who comes behind you will have a horrible time figuring out why reflection is necessary to do anything and how this works. When a class calls a method it's easy to follow. When a class does reflection and all this weird stuff it's very hard to understand.

Comment: @ScottHannen Thanks for your suggestion, I appreciate it very much. I am not sure I could get a better solution without reflection, but I agree that it can be daunting without context. If I go on with this approach, I plan to hide/protect it using appropriate encapsulation and "clean code" practices such as factoring out methods and variables with intention-revealing names.

Answer (score 3):

Here is complete solution for getting value of property:

```
var types = GetType().Assembly.GetTypes()
   .Where(type => type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(CodedCommand)) && !type.IsAbstract);

foreach (var type in types)
{
    var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    var field = type.GetProperty("Code", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    var value = field.GetValue(obj);
    var code = (char)value;

    _typeMap[code] = type;
}
```

Please note that `field.GetValue` needs object instance to work and `NonPublic`-BindingFlag is needed when getting PropertyInformation for internal property.

Comment: Those two `Where` should be combined with a `&&` BTW

Comment: Thanks for noticing, improved that.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your property is marked as `internal`, not `public` and we cannot access the non-public properties using the overload which you are using.

You need to specify the `flags` parmeter by using [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zy0d4103(v=vs.110).aspx) if you want properties other than `public` like:

```
type.GetProperty("Code",BindingFlags.Instance | 
                        BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                        BindingFlags.Public)
```

[`GetProperty(String)` overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kz0a8sxy(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Searches for the public property with the specified name.

[`GetProperty(string name,BindingFlags bindingAttr)` overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zy0d4103(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Searches for the specified property, using the specified binding constraints.

Comment: Who told you you cannot access non-public properties through reflection? This is completely incorrect. Just look at the `BindingFlags` enumeration, specially the `NonPublic` member

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto it's actually wrong overload that is the issue, we need to specify the `BindingFlags`

Comment: Your answer still claims something that's completely false

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto i understnad what you mean, rectified that statement

Comment: Well that solved one symptom, but I still cannot get the value of the property, since "Non-static method requires a target"... Any suggestion?

Comment: @heltonbiker: You cannot pass `null` to `GetValue`, then. For quite obvious reasons, as instance properties require, well, an instance to read from.